# Java swing - Receiving a Strings or ints from gui for an internal class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

Hello everyone I am not really working on the GUI for my project, but I am wondering what I should do for portions of the code where I need users inputs.. I am pretty new with Java GUI, but it is what we need to use for my class.

My part of the code is just to receive some int from the user most likely a slider between 0 and 10. This will determine their pain rating for certain problems they are having, and I have these set up in an array since there will be 10 things that can be wrong with them this is my code as follows:

```
public void inputPain() {
    int[] pain_rating = new int[10];
    Arrays.fill(this.pain_rating, 0);
    // ^ do I need this if all sliders will be set at zero initially? 

    // This is where I don't know how to receive an int from the GUI
    // presumably there will be 10 sliders that will be for each issue
    // which makes me think it is something like

    this.pain_rating[index] = pain;

    // where index is the slider the user chose and pain is the number 
    // the user slid it to
}
```

The only issue is I don't know how to receive these ints from the user from a GUI.. Just some idea on where I go from here would be awesome.. And thanks in advance

Comment: If it's a console application, use the `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: [How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you create a slider [as per this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html), you use event handlers to get the values from the inputs. The relevant part of the tutorial is

```
framesPerSecond.addChangeListener(this);
```

Which adds a change event handler to `framesPerSecond` (the slider). The event handler happens to be `this` (but it could be anything). The event handler merely has to implement the `ChangeListener` interface, which has a single method, `public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)`. Then the value of the slider is obtained with

```
JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
(int)source.getValue();
```

But do see the tutorial for more information.

Of course, it doesn't have to be a slider to get numeric data. You could just as easily use a text input and try to parse it as an integer (ie, with `Integer.parseInt(String)`), displaying some kind of error if the input can't be parsed as an integer.

For the most part, you'll find most GUI libraries use event handlers (aka "listeners") to react to the user.

Comment: Okay I got it makes sense... I guess I am going to have to wait till the other team members upload the GUI portion of our project to see if they are using sliders or a text field.. Though they said they were using sliders so I will just have to wait... Thanks for the information though I will be sure to read through this sliders tutorial to make sure I understand it fully before the GUI is uploaded